# Attachments don't work when sending email after deploying to azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, gmail, blazor

I have a web application that sends emails from one gmail account to another to notify me that an event has occurred on my website.  Working locally it works as intended, I am able to send emails with a body, subject and attachments as expected.  However, When I deploy my application to azure the attachments are removed, there isn't anything suggesting that the email was modified on either email.

Here is the code that is used to send the email:

```
 using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            try
            {
                if (userImageStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(userImageStream, "Customer.jpg", "image/jpeg"));
                    
                }
                if (exImageStream.Length > 0)
                {
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(exImageStream, "Example.jpg", "image/jpeg"));
                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            mail.From = new MailAddress(maileraddress);
            mail.To.Add(mailTarget);
            mail.Subject = "subject";
            mail.Body = mailBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

          
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(maileraddress, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
            }
        }
```

I have tried quite a few things programmatically. I can say that for sure the files are uploaded either to a stream or file (depending on configuration). I tried making a outlook account with the gmail email and using smtp.live.com which also didn't work.  I think this has something to do with azure (which i have just started using a day or two ago) and I have no idea where to go or what to do.  I have seen something about this problem occurring when people are downloading from blobs (I don't know what that is, and i really don't want to yet if possible) but I couldn't figure out how to leverage that answer to solve my problem. I really am stuck here and any help is greatly appreciated.  Please keep in mind that I am a novice programmer and my knowledge of azure is basically just enough to get a website up.

After some more testing it appears the files are still null after upload.  I'm not saving to file system only to a variable so I'm still confused.

Update:  managed to ssh into server, it appears the files aren't being saved.  I'm still looking into it any insight will be appreciated.

Can anyone answer if it is even possible to deal with a file that is temporarily uploaded with out being required to use blob storage?

Apparently I dont need to use blob storage but I cant get it to save anyways even with webrootpath.  I decided to go back to using streams again and it sends a file but it cant be opened,  I'm guessing it might be fixed but I'm not sure.  I'll update if I find solution.

Finally- after going back to using streams it works.  I'm frustrated that I missed it before chasing my tail but here I am and its finished.

Comment: Try deploying a version of this that has verbose logging for each path?  That's usually my goto

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Even though I got it working you are right. I need to use logging.  I just started with azure and have limited experience in general and haven't figured out how to log and access logs yet lol.

Comment: I confess, I didn't read your update at first glance.  It would be good for you to "answer your own question" so that it is marked as answered, and to separate the answer from the question. And congrats on getting that working... I'll be studying it soon for my own work.